# What tense is this sentence in? "Having had"

Tags: tense

What tense is this sentence in?

> For those who are already teaching without **having had** specific training and for practiced teachers ...

Is it a special structure?
What would happen if I removed "had"?
What are other alternatives?

Comment: It's not actually a sentence, but a preposition phrase, just part of a sentence - perhaps a complement. "Having had specific training" is a non-finite verb phrase (it is 'untensed') functioning as complement to the prep "without" which heads the PP "Without having had specific training". "Had" is required, since it is needed to locate the situation of the lack of training as anterior to that of the teaching.

Comment: @BillJ: I don't think ***had*** is "required" here. It's perfectly valid, and can be justified, but that doesn't imply it's *necessary*.

Comment: An incomplete sentence.  You can say without specific training, without having specific training, or without having had specific training.

Comment: I agree with Khan about the correct possibilities the sentence could have. And the tense —as is clear— is present perfect. To me, the sentence is well formed as it is, and better than other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to express present participles or gerunds in the perfect tenses or more accurately with the perfect *aspect* (whether or not a verb is "perfect" is technically an aspect and not a tense).

> I have gone to the store.
>
> Having gone to the store before, I already knew who the cashier was.
>
> Her having gone to the store is the evidence we needed to establish her as innocent.

*Have* can of course has present perfect, past perfect, etc. forms like any other verb.  Thus *having had* would be *have had* in participle or gerund form.

As *having had* is an object of the preposition *without*, it is functioning as noun, and therefore a gerund.